# If there's a design pattern, shouldn't it be present throughout the sites?

Tags: discussion, design

So, Ask Ubuntu just got a facelift/new theme.  It's the Stack Exchange site I frequent the most. Also, recently, I have been looking for some work.

The top bar moving in to the left bar to maximize front and center real-estate on screen is good.  I don't like it, but I can recognize what it's doing and give it a pass, because I'm just not used to it yet.

The thing that threw me a little was that the footer is still so large.  Why would that be relevant? Because it seems like a weird divergence. I can accept that we want it all on the screen in the densest format all the time, but then wouldn't you want to slam the footer in to the left bar?

From a usability perspective, I like the job postings and being able to get there from the footer. However, I find myself just opening stackoverflow.com to open it from the right hand side-pane to get there. It would seem more efficient to put the footer in all that empty space in the left-hand side pane if we're trying to get it all on one screen.

Comment: Maybe it's a work in progress.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading/unclear, but it seems the **tl;dr is a discussion/feature request to move footer to the left navbar?** But I can't see the relevance between "job postings" and "getting there from the footer", when the jobs can already be accessed from Jobs on the left navbar?

Comment: I really don't need permanently visible links to "Enterprise" or "Press" or "Contact Us" when browsing SO. Those links belong in the footer because they're rarely used.

Comment: @RobotHumans regarding that... because SO is the only site with Jobs, and they're for software developer/programming jobs. These jobs won't be relevant on many other SE sites such as [SciFi.SE], [money.se], [interpersonal.se], [english.se], [gardening.se], etc...

Comment: @SomewhatMemorableName There are Project Manager and Linux Admin jobs on there too!